# How do i fix navigation bar that changes position absolute to fixed

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to get my navigation bar change from absolute to fixed with reactjs:

```
<nav className={
 this.props.location.pathname !== '/'
 ? 'header-menu-wrapper no-banner'
 : this.state.isFixed
 ? 'header-menu-wrapper m-fixed'
 : 'header-menu-wrapper'
}>
```

Only the homepage is changing navigation from absolute to fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't need to check location for position value? If so, you may use like:

```
<nav className={
  'header-menu-wrapper' + 
  (this.props.location.pathname !== '/' ? ' no-banner' : '') + 
  (this.state.isFixed ? ' m-fixed' : '')
}>
```

Or, you might want for the position value like:

```
(this.props.location.pathname !== '/' && this.state.isFixed ? ' m-fixed' : '')
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest taking a little bigger, but easier to read method:

```
let classes = ['header-menu-wrapper'];
if (this.props.location.pathname !== '/') {
    classes.push('no-banner');
}
if (this.state.isFixed) {
    classes.push('no-banner');
}
<nav className={classes.join(' ')} />
```

That way, it's a lot easier to add new/alter logic.

<sub>- I can't answer your question baed on the info you've given, bust if you can write if statement, this should be enough

 - One step better would be to add the logic for the class into an own function.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You could try this approach:

```
const { location: { pathname } } = this.props;
const { isFixed } this.state;

<nav
  className={[
    'header-menu-wrapper',
    pathname !== '/' ? 'no-banner' : null,
    isFixed ? 'm-fixed' : null
  ].join(' ').trim()}
}>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this approach

```
<nav className={ "header-menu-wrapper " + this.props.location.pathname !== '/' ? 'no-banner' : this.state.isFixed ? 'm-fixed' : '' }>
```

or use template literal

```
<nav className={`header-menu-wrapper ${this.props.location.pathname !== '/' ? 'no-banner' : this.state.isFixed ? 'm-fixed' : ''}`}>
```